# Entry point not found in dynamic link library api-ms-win-runtimel1-1-0.dll when trying to start Apache on XAMPP v 3.2.2

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp

Recently I've installed Xampp v3.2.2 on my Windows 7 PC. But when I tried to start Apache it showed:

> api-ms-win-runtimel1-1-0.dll` fill is missing

then I manually downloaded the file and pasted it to `System32` folder but now it shows:

> entry point not found in DLL

I also installed Windows 7 service pack 1 but it has the same problem.

[image]

I've tried so many things but the problem still remain. Can anyone give me an hint?

Comment: problem solved by installing vc_redist.x64 for my 64 bit windows 7

Comment: If some one facing same problem don't forget to install windows 7 service pack 1